# Remove self signed certificate from iOS (Device and Simulator)

Tags: ios, iphone, certificate

1. Use iOS Safari (on the Device or Simulator) to connect to a site that presents a self-signed certificate
2. iOS Safari asks you to accept the certificate before connecting
3. Accept the certificate
4. Future requests are never prompted again

How do I remove the certificate I accepted in step #3 from my Device or Simulator?

It isn't present in `Settings`->`General`->`Profiles`, and performing `Settings`->`Safari`->`Clear Cookies and Data` and `Settings`->`Safari`->`Clear History` also had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered this question in a comment above.
To make it clear:

For the Simulator delete the self signed certificate from your key-chain. For the device, just clear Cookies and Data: go to Settings->Safari

Answer (score -2):

Yes.  For the Simulator, go under the iOS Simulator menu to "Reset Contents and Settings..."

For the Device, go to Window->Organizer.  Connect your device.  Go under "Provisioning Profiles" for the **device**... **NOT** the library.  Highlight the profiles you want to delete and press the delete key.

That's it!

Comment: Artur, did you ever happen to get the answer for this question? thanks.

Comment: For the Simulator delete the self signed certificate from your key-chain. For the device, just clear Cookies and Data: go to Settings->Safari